# Main/Prefix Route for all Modules

Tags: routes, zend-framework3

For my zendframework 3 application i want to change the main route.
i have serveral modules with main and child routes like:
*module customer*
**www.domain.de/customer

www.domain.de/customer/add**

*module article*
**www.domain.de/article

www.domain.de/article/view**

so the customer and article routes are defined in their module -> module.config.php

i would like to add after www.domain.de/ and before **EACH** module a mainroute like

www.domain.de/**app/**customer...
www.domain.de/**app/**article...

Do you have any ideas where i can define this main route, or do i have to add it in each module before the main route there (app/customer, app/article, app/...)
Define app/ once for the hole project would be quite smarter ;-)

Thanks in advance for your help!
hardcoded greets
Stefan

Comment: Define it in your applications `/config/autoload/global.php` I suppose. Then each module's route config would need to add that route as a parent.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to define them in module's config. It will be easier to add or remove a module. Just comment your module's namespace in modules.php file and all it's settings/definations will be removed from application config. No un-used settings will remain in global config.